# Intersection of open affines is affine

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I would like to see a clear, rigorous and elementary proof of the following statement:

Let X be a (not necessary quasi-projective, separated) algebraic variety over the complex numbers, and let U,V be two affine open subsets of X. Then the intersection of U and V is affine.

Does the proof change if one substitutes "scheme" for "variety"?

Comment: This is homework

Comment: Nice question! Form Ravi's old notes (link follows): "Another nice property of varieties: the intersection of any two affine opens is
another affine open. I don't foresee using this, so I won't prove it, but you can find
a proof in Mumford (p. 55) or Hartshorne (Exercise II.4.4)." I might look there or think about it. http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/725/class12.pdf

Comment: Duh! I was confused... For schemes, this property is the most important consequence of *separatedness*. For non-separated schemes, it'll be wildly unture (there is a weaker notion of quasiseparatedness which means that intersections of open affines are *finite unions* of open affines, but there are schemes that don't even have this property.)

Comment: @llya: this is true and it is equivalent to say any algebraic variety is semi-separated. 

Comment: Ok, found! It is spelled out in Mumford's book. Before I was only looking in Hartshorne's.

Comment: Muthiah was right, it's easy: just take the diagonal inside the product of the two open affines etc.

Comment: The asnwer is in textbooks as quoted. But some comments. Thomason and Trobaugh have introduced a notion of semi-separatedness, which means that this scheme has an affine cover with affine double intersections. Of course, this is weaker than separatedness. In noncommutative geometry almost all interesting schemes are not semi-separated (principal example: quantum flag varieties). 

Comment: @DinakarMuthiah how do you know?

Comment: @Aknazar Kazhymurat: it was just me not remembering a well known and easy proof. Could have been moved to MathStackExchange (but now the question is too old to migrate, I'm afraid)